# Can I use webots to schedule task of existing demo?

Tags: webots

I want to implement some scheduling algorithm using webots, like FIFO, EDF(preemptible), to control automobile's tasks( like turn left, turn right).

But it looks like there's no way to control one task's preemption. So how can I create a task called B and preempt cpu in the real time when task A is running? (My teacher told me to use ptolemy to do it, but it's too hard for me to simulate a robot using that)

Comment: Which language are you using?